# Web crawling/scraping GWT based web pages

Tags: gwt, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl a web page that is built using GWT and uses the GWT RPC mechanism for AJAX calls. The page I am trying to crawl is not mine - so I can't edit the server side. I am very new to GWT and from my initial couple of days with it - I think that you can't de-serialize the data unless you've the case interface with you.

Am I right or Is there a way to crawl the data intelligently?

Comment: I was able to do it using htmlunit - that forces the java script to be executed before I get hold of the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using htmlunit and WebClient:

```java
//real code mixed with pseudo-code:
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3);
Map<String, String> urls = new HashMap<->();
LinkedList<String> urlsToVisit = new LinkedList<->();
urlsToVisit.put("http://some_gwt_app.com/#!home");
while (!urlsToVisit.isEmpty()) {
    String page = urlsToVisit.remove();
    if (urls.containsKey(page)) { 
        continue;
    }
    String rendered = webClient.getPage(page);
    urls.put(page, rendered);
    urlsToVisit.addAll(extractLinks(page));
}
```

You might have to experiment with the WebClient options a bit. In my case these seem to do a good job:

```java
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
// important! Give the headless browser enough time to execute
// JavaScript. The exact time to wait may depend on your application.
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20000);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
```

Comment: How do you suggest extractLinks be implemented?

Comment: @wytten that's another question (HTML parsing) :)

Comment: I'm specifically interested in what constitutes a link in this context: "a", "link", "script", other tags?

Comment: ah I see now what you're trying to ask, totally makes sense. Maybe @gokul can answer for his case? Guess it depends on what you want to crawl. You could go for all GWT ajax links  - #!someUrl, and also anchor tags. I wouldn't go for GWT remote calls, they might be non-idempotent so you can destroy stuff on the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

I scrape for a living, and GWT is the one framework that almost always flummoxes me. The fact that it passes serialized, non-human readable parameters prevents me from interject logic that will access the site.

On some simple GWT I've gotten scrapes to work be parsing the JavaScript and running portions as is, but I can't get all to work.